# Variable throwing error within a VBA find function

Tags: excel, vba, variables, find

I'm trying to use a variable within a find command, but every time I get to the line of code with the find command on it, I get Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. However, if I set the variable by writing out a string rather than using Range().Value, the code works fine. ISBN is storing a variable after the line of code, and it will let me set other cells to that value. Pasting my code below. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Below is the code throwing the error:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ISBN As String

ISBN = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

Sheets("Frontlist - In House Audio").Select
Range("D:D").Find(What:=ISBN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select
End Sub
```

However, the code below works exactly as expected with the variable manually set:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ISBN As String

ISBN = "9780310358268"

Sheets("Frontlist - In House Audio").Select
Range("D:D").Find(What:=ISBN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `ISBN` is changing with each iteration of the loop in the first code snippet. Then, the `Find` is failing when a value is not found. You need to test if the `Find` succeeded.

Comment: True! This code doesn't test whether each find actually works yet, but I can't even get to the end of the loop because the initial Find function fails before the next iteration of i. Even if I run it as a set value like this, ISBN = Range("A2").Value, I still get the same error.

Comment: You also need to qualify what worksheet the `Range("A2")` is on.

Comment: Never used reserved words like `Rows` as a variable name. Be more specific or call it `myRows` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test if the `Find` succeeded *before* attempting to do anything with the result, which would include attempting to `Select`.

You *also* need to qualify the worksheet that `Range("A2")` is on.

```vb
Dim numRows As Long

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to numRows
    ISBN = Worksheets("worksheetname").Range("A" & i).Value   

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = Worksheets("Frontlist - In House Audio").Find( _
        What:=ISBN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then '<~ test if the Find succeeded
        ' do whatever with foundCell
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! This resolved my first problem. Now, though, when I use this code, the FoundCell value is being set to the What:=ISBN value rather than the range of the cell with that value. ```Set FoundCell = Worksheets("Frontlist - In House Audio").Range("D:D").Find(What:=ISBN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "range of the cell with that value"? Maybe an example of what `FoundCell` is now and what it should actually be?

Comment: Nevermind! I realized the code I was using to test the FoundCell value was set to pull the value rather than the cell address. My mistake -  thanks for your help!